# How to interpret the contents of /lost+found after serious filesystem corruption?

Tags: linux, redhat, filesystems

I am trying to work out whether some serious filesystem corruption is recoverable or not - however, I am struggling to find a definitive description of what i am seeing in /lost+found anywhere on the web.

Can someone describe the different fields (columns) for me in the following output please?:

```
/<directory>/lost+found:

total 2068
c---r----t   1  563216355 3786404617 254,   0 Mar 12  1972 #101010477
b-----x-wx   1 3760447531 3930169908   7, 161 Dec 21  1953 #101262077
pr-S---r-t   1  738401804  404783880        0 Aug  5  1979 #10134481
-r-S-wxr-T   1 1197902768     984580    45056 Aug 24  1997 #101786960
```

This is only part of the output, but I would like to know what columns 3, 4 and 5/6 correspond to if anyone knows? The timestamps are messed up too, but I assume that is because the metadata is too corrupt to read correctly?

Comment: That's just a symptom, it's not going to help you solve the problem, can you describe what happened and what you best outcome would be?

Comment: Yes, i know it's a symptom - that's why I want to know how to interpret the output (then I will have a better idea on how to proceed)!?

We had a disk array playing up, which appears to have changed the size of the LUN presented to the host; this, in turn, has caused massive filesystem corruption across several filesystems. We are seeing errors documented in this RedHat article: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/21135

I just want to know what the fields/columns/output above corresponds to, so that I can either try and recover the files or rebuild the filesystem.

Comment: but that's a red herring, the problem is with the LUN - was the LUN resized to reclaim 'unused space' from a partition? - the red hat article explains that your file system is trying to address space it no longer has, what is a RAID 0 LUN? - what is the root of the problem - disk failure, resize live filesystem on SAN, - if you rebuild (i.e shrink the filesystem) with a missing disk you will lose everything on that disk and corrupt many files on the remaining disk in the LUN